# how to solve this issue while typing text is correct after is not correct?

Tags: phaser-framework

how to solve this issue while typing text is correct after is not correct. seen in images

After
[image: After Image]
While Typing

[image: While Typing]

```
 var textInput = this.add.sprite(400, 380, 'textinput').setScale(0.6, 0.6);
    const text = this.add.text(0, 0, '', { fixedWidth: 200, fixedHeight: 36 })
    text.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5)

    text.setInteractive().on('pointerdown', () => {
        this.rexUI.edit(text)
    })

    Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(text, textInput);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the parameter `{ fixedWidth: 200, fixedHeight: 36 }`. Since those *fixed* sizes are used for the calculation, and by default the text is aligned top-right.

If you remove that parameter the text should be align in the **center** of the `sprite`. Alternativly you could try setting the alignment of the text, with the function `setAlgin` ([link to documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Text.html#setAlign__anchor)), but this only will change the horizontal alignment, not the vertical one.

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 160,
    scene: {
        create
    }
}; 

function create () {
    let rect1 = this.add.rectangle(150, 80, 100, 50, 0xffffff)
      .setOrigin(0);
    
    let rect2 = this.add.rectangle(150, 10, 100, 50, 0xffffff)
      .setOrigin(0);
    
    let text1 = this.add.text(0, 160, 'TEXT 1 TEXT 1 TEXT 1')
        .setBackgroundColor('#ff00ff');
        
    let text2 = this.add.text(0, 160, 'TEXT 2 TEXT 2', { fixedWidth: 200, fixedHeight: 36 })
        .setBackgroundColor('#ff00ff')
        .setAlign('center');
    
    Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(text1, rect1)
    Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(text2, rect2)
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: it solved using padding

Answer (score 0):

Using Padding `{ fixedWidth: 200, fixedHeight: 40, padding: 8, })`